# Out-of-the-box Eclipse PDT (PHP Development Tool) not capable of debugging PHP, why?

Tags: php, windows, eclipse-pdt

I *just* finished reinstalling the "All-In-One Eclipse PDT" from zend.com. It's unable to debug even the simplest "Hello World" PHP script. How can such a major open-source app be released in such a bad shape? What am I doing wrong?

This is the result of doing a "Debug As... 2. PHP Script":

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: php.exe
  Application Version:  5.2.9.9
  Application Timestamp:    49dda267
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.18005
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49e03824
  Exception Code:   c0000130
  Exception Offset: 0006f04e
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 9d13
  Additional Information 2: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
  Additional Information 3: 9d13
  Additional Information 4: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

I think it wants me to configure some additional stuff, but I have no clue what exactly to do.

Comment: Am I supposed to install XAMPP? WAMP? XDebug? I thought PDT "All-In-One" meant all in one... no extras to install.

Comment: Because it's terrible.  Use something better suited to PHP development like NetBeans or PHPStorm

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your PHP installation as in [this thread](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=29684&start=0&sid=26464f88dc9490ac7b88481c53080b51&view=print)?

> > After uninstalling `XAMPP` and reinstalling it (`xampp-win32-1.7.0-installer.exe`) and applying the `xampp-patch2-win32-1.7.0-installer`, I still have the problem of the PHP CLI closing and throwing the pop-up dialog.
>
> OK, you must also copy "`php_mysql_5.0.51a.dll`" to "`php_mysql.dll`" and "`php_mysqli_5.0.51a.dll`" to "`php_mysqli.dll`" in "`\xampp\php\ext`".

Comment: do I need XAMPP? What for. Just want to debug a simple CLI PHP script

Comment: @Alex: no, this was in case you had XAMPP installed. As mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Debugger, PDT does not contain a server side implementation for PHP debugging. As mentioned here (http://www.thierryb.net/pdtwiki/index.php?title=Using_PDT_:_Installation_:_Installing_PDT), a PHP debugger like Zend is needed (http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt#debugger)

Comment: I seem to be going around in circles. One of the links takes me to "Download Only the PHP Debugger. To debug your code locally, before deploying to a Web server, download the Zend Executable Debugger Eclipse Plug-in (Note: this plug-in is included in the all-in-one package)." But the all-in-one is what I started out with, from the very same web page.

Comment: Going to http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Debugger took me to http://downloads.zend.com/pdt ... that looked very promising but then the updater said I already have it installed, and prompted me to update. Let's see what happens.

Comment: The update fails with:

Install has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed


session context was:(profile=epp.package.php, phase=org.eclipseequinoxinternal.provisional.p2.engini No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger,5.3.7.v20091116 No repository found containing: org.eclipseupdatefeature,org.zend.php.debug_feature,5.3.7.v20091116 No repository found containing: osgibundle,org.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32x26,5.3.7.v20091116

Comment: @Alex: may be this could be related to http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/pdt-dev/msg00933.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your version of xdebug extension correct? Try the latest release 
[xdebug website](http://xdebug.org/download.php)

Comment: do I need to install XDebug on top of Zend Eclipse PDT All-In-One in order for the Zend Debugger to work?

Comment: If you have installed Zend Debugger — no.
Have you checked your phpinfo(), is Zend Debugger extension properly loaded?